# How do I split up a large .iso file across multiple DVDs via command line tools?

Tags: iso, dvd

Say I have an ISO file that is 5GB in size. How can I split it across 2 DVDs? Please I'm looking for an actual example showing me how to do it, not just recommendations.

The solution would leave the files written to disk in a browseable state, not requiring another tool to reassemble the pieces before being accessible.

I'm currently using this type of a command to author the ISO file:

```
$ mkisofs -o $backup -r -J -hide-rr-moved -V "Backup $date" \
    -graft-points " dir1 dir2
```

And then this command to author a DVD with the resulting ISO file:

```
$ growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=$backup
$ mkisofs -o $backup -r -J -hide-rr-moved -V "Backup $date" \
    -graft-points " dir1 dir2
```

And then this command to author a DVD with the resulting ISO file:

```
$ growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=$backup
```

Comment: Why not use `gaffitter`/`gaff-iso` or similar to create suitable sized ISOs in the first place?

Comment: @frostschutz - never heard of that tool, will check in the mean time.

Comment: Easiest approach: Buy a DVD9 (dual layer) blank. Most burners can burn them. All readers can read them.

Comment: @derobert - yeah I know I could do that but still wanted to know how to span the data, if possible 8-)

Comment: SquashFS? Otherwise, I'd probably write a FUSE driver that made them look like a single block device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be possible without repacking the ISO into
two separate ones.

There is only one Primary Volume Descriptor in the ISO
image by which the readers can find the tree of 
directories and files.

You would have at least to create a second such PVD
and a second directory tree, which allow access to
the files on the second DVD.
Further you would have to remove those files from
the first directory tree which get stored on the
second DVD. Else you get i/o errors when trying to
read those files.

Comment: This is the correct answer.